# CCRepeatAction causing Win32 App to crash on closing

Tags: c++, winapi, cocos2d-x, win32gui, ccaction

Could someone help me figure out how to safely stop all actions when closing a Win32 cocos2dx app that is running CCRepeatAction. I have tried adding `sprite->stopAllActions();` in the `Destructor`, `OnExit()` and in the `update(float delta);` methods but still app crashes when I click on the 'X' button of my running Win32 Cocos2dx app.

I am not retaining the CCRepeatAction and I have also tried just letting Cocos2D-X stop the running action when it does its cleanup, but it seems like if a CCAction is running while app is closed then app crashes. So my assumption is that the action has to be stopped when closing the Win32 App.

The repeat forever action is running on my idle state. It is a simple fadeIn/fadeOut CCAction. Here is the code for my Idle state animation. I am not retaining it so not sure how to stop the animation and close the app without crashing it.

```
if ( idleAnim == true ) 
{
    this->getSprite()->stopAllActions();
    CCSequence *actions = CCSequence::create(CCFadeIn::create(0.5f), CCFadeOut::create(0.5f),NULL);
    CCRepeatForever *repeat = CCRepeatForever::create(actions);
    this->getSprite()->runAction(repeat);
    idleAnim = false;
}
```

Comment: Check your return values and use a debugger.

Comment: Hi Captain Obvlious, thanks for responding. I was debugging but was not getting anywhere. I followed the stack closely and the issue seems to be that GameLayer class was removing the SpriteBatchNode, so when my Character class' destructor tried to remove the sprite `sprite_->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);` from spritebatch it crashed-bad reference to removed memory location. I retained the SpriteBatchNode inside my character class, that resolved the issue. So now if I abruptly close app with animation running, it does not crash/break app.